# Saving the shortest paths in a graph using the Floyd Warshall algorithm in java

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, tree, graph-theory

I am trying to write a Betweeness Centrality method for a undirected, unweighted (weight = 1) Graph in Java. The way I have gone about it is by finding all of the shortest paths in the graph, and then iterating through those paths and counting how often a vertex is a step in that path. I have used the Floyd Warshall algorithm to find the shortest paths, and used another array to reconstruct the paths, similar to the [pseudo code on the Wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm)

However, my results are not correct, and I have tried figuring out where the problem lies but I can't. I will just post the whole code in here for completeness sake, however it is messy so I apologize. I will comment the bits where I think the problems would occur.

```
public void calculateBetweenessCentrality() {
    // Floyd warshall algorithm, storing paths with R
    int noPath = Integer.MAX_VALUE / 4;
    int[][] adjMatrix = getAdjacencyMatrix();
    int distances[][] = new int[numVertices][numVertices];
    int[][] R = new int[numVertices][numVertices];

    // Initialize the arrays, setting "-5000" as null instead. Possible error here?
    for (int i = 0; i < numVertices; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < numVertices; j++) {
            if (adjMatrix[i][j] == 0) { 
                distances[i][j] = noPath;
                R[i][j] = -5000; // null
            }
            else {
                distances[i][j] = adjMatrix[i][j];
                R[i][j] = j;
            }

        }
    }
    // Do the algorithm, and save in R, possible error here?
    for (int k = 0; k < numVertices; k++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < numVertices; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < numVertices; j++) {
                if (distances[i][j] > distances[i][k] + distances[k][j]) {
                    distances[i][j] = distances[i][k] + distances[k][j];
                    R[i][j] = R[i][k];
                }

            }
        }
    }

    // Go through R and construct the shortest paths, record the frequency for each node (indexs). Possible error here?
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> frequencies = new HashMap<>(); // Key = index, Value = frequency
    for (int i = 0; i < numVertices; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < numVertices; j++) {
            ArrayList<Integer> path = findShortestPath(R, i, j);
            for (int p : path) {
                int freq = frequencies.containsKey(p) ? frequencies.get(p) : 0;
                frequencies.put(p, freq + 1);
            }
        }
    }

    HashMap<Integer, Integer> temp = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>(); // Instead of printing the vertex's adjacency matrix index value, get the actual value for displaying purposes.
    for (Entry<Integer, Integer> freq : frequencies.entrySet()) {
        temp.put(verticesIndexValue.get(freq.getKey()), freq.getValue());

    }
    System.out.println("Top 5 nodes: \nNode - Count");
    frequencies.entrySet().stream().sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Collections.reverseOrder())).limit(5)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (e1, e2) -> e1, LinkedHashMap::new))
            .forEach((node, frequency) -> System.out.println(node + " - " + frequency));

}

private ArrayList<Integer> findShortestPath(int[][] R, int u, int v) {

    ArrayList<Integer> paths = new ArrayList<>();

    if(R[u][v] == -5000)
        return paths;

    paths.add(u);
    while(u != v) {
        u = R[u][v];
        paths.add(u);
    }

    return paths;
}
```

The graph that I am testing this on is from [this input here](https://pastebin.com/jWJyYBC9), where each line is an edge. The graph in that pastebin creates two connected components. The output I get for the first component is as follows:

```
Top 5 nodes: 
Node - Count
11336782 - 11393
50393960 - 9047
627363 - 4079
849131 - 3799
5676102 - 3351
```

The answer is actually that 50393960 is the top node. If anybody could please guide me to where I am going wrong, I'd appreciate it massively. Thanks =)

Answer (score 2):

Your code contains mistake in the place where it calculates frequencies - according to definition of Betweenness centrality when calculating it for particular vertex `V`  you should exclude shortest paths which start or end with vertex `V`. Basically it means that when iterating over shortest paths you shoud not add start and end vertexes to frequencies. Try this instead:

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> frequencies = new HashMap<>(); // Key = index, Value = frequency
for (int i = 0; i < numVertices; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < numVertices; j++) {
        ArrayList<Integer> path = findShortestPath(R, i, j);
        for (int p : path) {
            if (p == i || p == j) {
               continue;
            }
            int freq = frequencies.containsKey(p) ? frequencies.get(p) : 0;
            frequencies.put(p, freq + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tested it but it doesn't fix it. Both of the vertices count are less, but the 11336782 node is still coming up as most frequent.

Comment: I've tested it on smaller graph and it was working fine. Are you sure your expected result it correct?

Comment: Turns out the definition of Betweeness centrality is wrong. We must consider ALL of the shortest paths from one node to another, not just the one shortest path. I believe Floyd Warshall can be modified to do this, I am trying to do it.